# gmail marks my mail as spam [SPF:pass,DKIM:pass,DMARK:pass;rDNS;pass]

Tags: linux, postfix, spam, gmail

I am trying to deploy my mail server with postfix but mails to google are always sent to spam.
I know this question has already been answered on another topic but I didn't find an appropriate solution for my problem.
This is the report of allaboutspam.com. It seems to say that everyting is ok: 
http://www.allaboutspam.com/email-server-test-report/?key=6F974B06B529A6362DFCA1FB5FB9C186

the header of the mail received by google is:

```
Delivered-To: 1234@gmail.com
Received: by 10.200.57.65 with SMTP id t1csp86463qtb;
    Mon, 9 Jan 2017 01:56:02 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.28.1.216 with SMTP id 207mr4417016wmb.7.1483955762247;
    Mon, 09 Jan 2017 01:56:02 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <4567@icaronet.tk>
Received: from icaro.icaronet.tk (icaro.icaronet.tk. [94.177.232.246])
    by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id 34si7837219wrj.128.2017.01.09.01.56.01
    for <1234@gmail.com>
    (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
    Mon, 09 Jan 2017 01:56:02 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of 4567@icaronet.tk designates 94.177.232.246      as permitted sender) client-ip=94.177.232.246;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
   dkim=pass header.i=@icaronet.tk;
   spf=pass (google.com: domain of 4567@icaronet.tk designates 94.177.232.246 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=4567@icaronet.tk;
   dmarc=pass (p=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=icaronet.tk
Received: by icaro.icaronet.tk (Postfix, from userid 1000)
id 7C67F62461; Mon,  9 Jan 2017 10:56:01 +0100 (CET)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=icaronet.tk;
s=201612; t=1483955761;
bh=AO2Rbj8RCi1Cx2vXFABRPdxa8dHIyAAnsLI0zalZP9s=;
h=To:Subject:Date:From:From;
b=rsvVlNum7UgKn2ugRSR+vE0K3fTJ8zMq7PnmtRnMhKXbTLZFQipDcHdmw4D/MnS6r
 nsXktYqrBvNcfnPFMv3spOzf80pcxKMZHgj8Yq4VlqMkxw7p4S1vntDTflDluHvBx4
 luHHTHq8ESu5F58qHvaPQKbZRxQwuV9BP/MCpn85AiUpsqgSwxBY8jcZzq4Q3dbuxe
 bhrIFIj8bpEH49b7neUSQzrF72qhpEecguyQGj8wuXh4dD8BvWRVSWxvRJLHtcVvzt
 0fldqKLF8QqzXtyYHXsRuZ89fVGf9fqYgmi/0E9EFNi93A+pGeyNiPX015VmPfk87A
 lNWV2bs/KUFBQ==
 To: 1234@gmail.com
 Subject: ALESSIO
Message-Id: <20170109095601.7C67F62461@icaro.icaronet.tk>
Date: Mon,  9 Jan 2017 10:56:01 +0100 (CET)
From: 4567@icaronet.tk

 nisl, cras egestas netus iaculis habitasse dictumst. Urna ac donec in ve quis placerat a, senectus. 
 Quis habitasse congue, a volutpat leo, euismod eget. Dapibus curae ante sem eni. Quisque ultrices ligula. Tempor consequat netus sed blandit morbi. Vulputate risus, lorem penatibus malesuada. Urna etiam mattis sapien eni, ante enim. Convallis neque ante fames eu tellus ve lectus cum, ad. Amet erat aliquet ante, est. Pretium ac, magna eu odio eget egestas donec neque ullamcorper bibendum egestas. Vel, mi cras gravida ut, phasellus facilisis. Nibh class viverra sit, ut aliquam eget eu urna praesent euismod laoreet eget. Augue et proin curae turpis suscipit. Sodales curabitur urna.
```

I noticed that the server is on the subnet `94.177.232.0/24` in which has been reported some spam servers.

How can I solve this problem? 
Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: **Google**'s `@gmail.com` offers these [recommendations](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?hl=en) , which you have already followed quite well with SPF and DKIM. You might want to subscribe to their [postmaster](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6227174) toolbox on [postmaster.google.com](http://postmaster.google.com) which is intended for domain owners.

Comment: How can I use the postmaster tools to improve my reputation to gmail? Also I don't really have such a big volume of mails. They say I need something like hundreds of mail to use the postmaster tools.